# iOS custom keyboard extension - Memory Limit

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, keyboard, ios-extensions

I am developing a custom keyboard in which I'm ridiculously facing the memory issue. I did all kind of instrumental observation and came to the conclusion that iOS is preserving the memory every time keyboard is appearing and invalidating. I'm very much frustrated of this behaviour because as in dealloc I'm already releasing all of my DMA though my project is in ARC.

Scenario is something like this:

`When I starts my keyboard for the first time it consumes approximately and after some operation it use to increase upto 30 MB and then I invalidate the keyboard. Again when I'm reloading it at that moment it starts from 30 MB which is totally unexpected and due to which after some transitions there is memory pressure and extension gets crashed.`

It will be very much helpful if anyone can suggest some idea to manage memory pressure.

Comment: Without any code, I can only guess: Maybe you have a retain cycle, so that the allocated memory cannot be released?

Comment: Its not possible to put all the codes here. There is no retain cycles as I checked them from Instruments. Problem is if you will create a simple extension then also you can see the same behaviour.

Comment: My experience has been that the leaks tool doesn't actually work pre-Xcode 6.3 beta 3+ for keyboard extensions, and in any event it is reliable only for very simple issues. Though I've often seen cases where the `UIinputViewController` doesn't get deallocated properly even though there is apparently no cycle, *every time* sounds an awful lot like a retain cycle to me.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer here is that you have a memory leak.

If you are writing you extension in Swift, add a break point to the `deinit` method in view controller that inherits from `UIInputViewController` and see if it gets called.

If you are writing your app in Objective-C then you can do the same thing from the deconstructor.

I too struggled with this and from my experience, the only thing that will stick around after closing the keyboard is some Core Data stuff. Other then that, if all your objects are owned by the primary view controller (`UIInputViewController`) then they will go away if they are no longer referenced.

If you still see a large amount of memory being used after the `deinit` is called then you have a leak elsewhere. Watch out for retain-release cycles and be careful with closures in Swift. Those are usually the culprits when it comes to memory leaks.

Without seeing any of your code I can't really provide any more specific information here.

Good luck!